# Trying to add google fonts to a react / neutrino project

Tags: reactjs, neutrino

trying Neutrino for the first time to jumpstart a react project. Want to add google fonts to it; tried passing google URLS in as a links array in config/html but no joy. suggestions?

Comment: [Have you checked the docs?](https://neutrino.js.org/packages/font-loader/)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could load Google fonts into your Web-based Neutrino project.

---

The easiest would probably be to install the font you would like from npm, such as Works Sans:

```
npm install --save typeface-work-sans
```

Which you can then import into your project with:

```
import 'typeface-work-sans';
```

---

The second method would involve the links way you mentioned, by adding an external stylesheet to your local Web-based `.neutrinorc.js` (using `react` for this example):

```
// .neutrinorc.js
module.exports = {
  use: [
    ['@neutrinojs/react', {
      html: {
        links: [
          {
            href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans',
            rel: 'stylesheet'
          }
        ]
      }
    }]
  ]
};
```